# How to use conditions to select a where clause

Tags: mysql

I am trying to set a search filter to my view. Normally the view returns the full data table. Now i have 3 filter fields for this first name, last name, and country. I want if the user presses search while all are empty it will return all the data in the db. but if even on field has a string it will return all the values matching that string of that field. similarly if other fields are also full the returned data will be the rows matching the corresponding strings in the fields.

Since i have used pagination using stored procedure i would prefer to use stored procedures for this as well. But i am not as well versed in mysql so i don't really know how to structure my query so that i can check all the conditions in the query and return the result from there instead of getting the data first and then filtering it.

I need the db to return nothing if even one input doesn't matches its corresponding value. but so far i am getting all the row if all the fields have a value and even one field is wrong, and i get the rows even if they do not match with the previous field for example:
if i search a john in first name and enter kelly in the last naem i will get all the john's and kelly's whether the first name doesnt match.

**My stored Procedure:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetFilterResult]
@PageIndex INT,  
@pageSize INT,
@attr1 nvarchar(300),
@attr2 nvarchar(300),
@attr3 nvarchar(300)
    AS
    Begin
    SELECT  Accounts.firstName, Accounts.lastName, Accounts.Email, 
    Accounts.dateOfBirth, Accounts.phoneNo, Countries.CountryName 

    FROM Accounts INNER JOIN Countries On Accounts.CountryID = 
    Countries.CountryID

    Where (Accounts.firstName LIKE CONCAT('%', @attr1, '%') and 
    Accounts.lastName LIKE CONCAT('%', @attr2, '%') and Accounts.CountryID 
    Like CONCAT('%', @attr3, '%')) 

    or (Accounts.firstName LIKE CONCAT('%', @attr1, '%') and 
    Accounts.lastName LIKE CONCAT('%', @attr2, '%') and @attr3 like CONCAT 
    ('null'))

    or (Accounts.firstName LIKE CONCAT('%', @attr1, '%') and 
    Accounts.CountryID LIKE CONCAT('%', @attr3, '%') and @attr2 like CONCAT 
    ('null'))

    or (Accounts.CountryID LIKE CONCAT('%', @attr3, '%') and 
    Accounts.lastName LIKE CONCAT('%', @attr2, '%')and @attr1 like CONCAT 
    ('null'))

    or (Accounts.firstName LIKE CONCAT('%', @attr1, '%')and @attr3 like 
    CONCAT ('null') and @attr2 like CONCAT ('null'))

    or (Accounts.lastName LIKE CONCAT('%', @attr2, '%')and @attr3 like 
    CONCAT ('null') and @attr1 like CONCAT ('null'))

    or (Accounts.CountryID LIKE CONCAT('%', @attr3, '%')and @attr1 like 
    CONCAT ('null') and @attr2 like CONCAT ('null'))

    ORDER BY UserId OFFSET @PageSize*(@PageIndex-1) ROWS FETCH NEXT

    @PageSize ROWS ONLY;

    END
```

Comment: I think you must handle the values of attr1, attr2, attr3 through front-end and then use them only once in the search predicate.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai i can do that but i was hoping to find a way to do it in mysql, becuase i will have to make multiple stored procedures in that case.